# New badge format for Chess.SE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, badges

Most sites use the standard circle badge, but some like English Language Learners (ELL).SE have a custom badge shape, is it possible for the Chess.SE site to have a custom one too (a rook shaped badge)?

[image]

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from earlier this week: [Custom Chess SE design and logo - Information gathering](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1121/29692) :)

Comment: Update: [Your new site design is live!](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1178/29692) – and it includes some great-looking custom badge designs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently only done for sites which have a custom design. For sites with the plain Beta design, only the site logo can be changed.

Coincidence or not, new custom designs are currently being rolled out to seven sites ([example](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4448/13538)). We can hope Chess Stack Exchange is one of the next sites, but there are many more sites on the list:

- [Congratulations to our 29 oldest beta sites - They're now no longer beta!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta)
- [Congratulations to the 59 sites that just left Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374096/congratulations-to-the-59-sites-that-just-left-beta)

When that happens, one of the designers will post a question here asking for input, and you will be able to post an answer with suggestions. IMHO, a chess piece will certainly work as badge icon, but I'd use a different one than in the logo.